All solutions for $a^2 + 5a + 19 = b^2$ where a and b are positive integers
we have to find integer solutions to the equation.
$$a^2 + 5a + 19 = b^2$$
The solution starts with multiplying everything by $4$ to yield
$$4a^2 + 20a + 76 = 4b^2$$
Then completing the square yields
$$(2a+5)^2+51=4b^2$$
The solution then proceeds to bring the $(2a+5)^2$ to the other side, factor (since difference difference of squares) to arrive at
$$(2b+2a+5)(2b-2a-5)=51$$
From there is fairly straight forward to arrive at the solution that $(a,b)$ is $(1,5)$ and $(10,13)$
My question how did they know to multiply by $4$ and then complete the square. To be honest, I didn't even know where to start? Are there any clues in the question that would suggest something? To me multiplying by $4$ seems magic!
Thank you for any insight,

These problems are always of the same trick; one of these tricks is to try to factor the equation. The hint in this problem is that you have squares, so you can try to use difference of squares. Then you just notice that if you wanna complete the square, you have to multiply by 4 first

@DanielP I second the comment of Dan Uznanski.  I suggest that you delete your comment, and transplant it into an answer.  Basically, you are looking for a small positive integer scalar that is both even and a perfect square.

Well, my natural instinct was to think of a generalized Pell equation $$x^2 - Dy^2 = N,$$
which we could obtain if we remove the linear term of the quadratic in $a$ via a suitable translation--i.e., complete the square.  So let's do that directly:
$$a^2 + 5a + 19 = (a + \tfrac{5}{2})^2 - \tfrac{25}{4} + 19 = (a + \tfrac{5}{2})^2 + \tfrac{51}{4}.$$
Consequently the original equation becomes
$$b^2 - (a + \tfrac{5}{2})^2 = \tfrac{51}{4}.$$
But in the generalized Pell equation, $D$ and $N$ are integers.  So this suggests we need to multiply everything by $4$, which is conveniently a square:
$$4b^2 - (2a + 5)^2 = 51.$$  And at this point, we notice that in fact, $D = 1$, because we can let $x = 2b$ and $y = 2a+5$, and we no longer need to use the Pell method to solve it, as the difference of squares $$x^2 - y^2 = (x + y)(x - y)$$ factors.  This line of reasoning ends up replicating the solution that you provided.

Thank you for this reply. I had not heard of a Pell equation before. That is also a reason to complete the square.

You don't have to multiply by 4 straight away! If you have the idea to complete the square, you might immediately do it to get
$$ \left(a+\frac52\right)^2+\frac{51}4 = b^2. $$
But we are trying to find integers $a,b$ that solve the equation, so isn't it quite annoying to have fractions in the expression? After all, to solve for integer solutions we might usually find it nice that the equation itself only has integers too (makes divisibility analysis easier, for example). So let's multiply by 4 now, to clear denominators. That's the motivation.
Of course with more experience you might be able to immediately recognise from the very first step that you would eventually need to multiply by 4, and so do it straight away (which is probably why whoever wrote your solution did it that way). By doing so you cosmetically simplify the answer by preventing any fractions from arising in the first place, but it is obviously mathematically equivalent!

Thank you for this response. It actually was not even obvious to me that you should complete the square. I was trying to bring the $b^2$ over and then factor but couldn't go further. Out of curiosity, how did you recognize that completing the square was the way to go?

@MathNewb I suppose this comes from experience. What you did is also a reasonable thing to try, but once this doesn't work, completing the square is also a natural idea that comes to mind for me, just because it's a typical way to try to manipulate things algebraically when there's a quadratic expression involved. It's just the association "quadratic <-> complete the square" here, I think.

Thank you for that response. I will have to remember to add that as a way of trying to solve these types of questions.

Your solutions $(x,y)=(1,5)$ and $(10,13)$ are the only positive ones.
In fact all other positive solution must be such that both $x$ and $y$ be greater than $10$ and $13$ respectively. So  we prove that
$$(10+x)^2+5(10+x)+19=(13+y)^2$$ has no positive solution. Simplifying we have
$$25x+x^2=26y+y^2\\(x-y)(25+x+y)=y$$ which is impossible for both integer positive $x,y$.
.

I would have done it the following way: Narrow down the set of solutions to a set small enough to check each element directly. Indeed, first note:
$$b^2 - (a+2)^2 = a+15.$$
So $b^2$ has to be a square bigger than $(a+2)^2$. However, the next smallest square after $(a+2)^2$ is $(a+3)^2$, and so $b^2$ must also satisfy the condition:
$$b^2 - (a+2)^2 \ge (a+3)^2 - (a+2)^2 = 2a+5.$$
Thus, from the above we note the following inequality:
$$a+15 \ge 2a+5,$$
or $10 \ge  a$ or equivalently, $a \le 10$.
It's not that much work to go through $a=\{1,2,\ldots, 10\}$  from here on out, to check for which such values of $a$ is $a^2+5a+19$ a square. If that still is not enough narrowing down, note that all integral squares are $0,1 \pmod 4$ to note that $a$ cannot be $0 \pmod 4$ or $3 \pmod 4$. So you only need to check the integers $a \in \{1,2,5,6,9,10\}$.
I bring up this idea as it is used a lot in solving Diophantine equations.

Thanks for adding this solution. There are a couple of insights you used here. One you brought the quadratics to one side and the linear on the other. Is this one of ways to solve a Diophantine equation? You very quickly brought down the sample space and checking 10 numbers is not that bad. And that mod trick is very nice!

@MathNewb thank you for the kind words but when you are done w your course on number theory you will see what I did in this post is just all in a day's work :) And you will know these tricks yourself. But yes 'the difference between any two large integral squares [or cubes, or 4th powers...], also has to be large so if the difference is not large both have to be small' comes up a lot indeed.

You should see what you can observe about positive integral solutions to, say, $a^2+7b+12=b^2$.

They multiplied by $4$ because $5$ is an odd number, and completing the square without multiplication would yield a $5/2$ term, which we don't want if we're looking for integer solutions. Moreover, we didn't multiply by $2$, because $2a^2=(\sqrt{2}a)^2$, and once again, $\sqrt{2}$ isn't an integer.


They didn't need to multiply by $4$.

$a^2+5a + 19=b^2\implies $
$(a^2+5a + \frac {25}4)+(19-\frac {25}4)=b^2\implies$
$ b^2-(a+\frac 52)^2=(b-a+\frac 52)(b-a-\frac 52) = \frac {51}4$
and then multiplying by $4$ seems an obvious thing to do.

You can always multiply be $4$ to complete a square to avoid those dang $\frac b2$ and $\frac {b^2}4$ fractions.

$x^2 + bx + c = 0$
$x^2+bx =-c$
$4x^2+4bx=-4c$
$(2x)^2 + 2b(2x) = -4c$
$(2x)^2 + 2b(2x) + b^2 = b^2-4c$
$(2x+b)^2 =b^2-4c$
$(2x+b) = \pm \sqrt{b^2-4c}$
$2x = -b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4c}$
$x =\frac {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4c}}2$
That should look very familiar.

The only reason we don't teach this this trick when learning the quadratic formula and completely the square in the first place, is the darned $a$ coefficient in $ax^2 + bx + c$ assures we are going to be dealing with fractions anyway so it'd only be confusing to make a big deal about avoiding $\frac b2$ but still dealing with $\frac 1a$.

But we could!
Suppose $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$.  Let $r$ be the rational number $\frac ba$ and $q$ be the rational number $\frac ca$.
$ax^2 + bx + c=0$
$4ax^2 + 4bx + 4c = 0$
$4x^2+4px +4q = 0$
$4x^2+4px =-4q$
$4x^2 + 4px + p^2 = p^2 -4q$
$(2x + p)^2 = p^2-4q$
$2x + p = \pm \sqrt {p^2-4q}$
$x = \frac {-p \pm \sqrt{p^2-4q}}2$
$= \frac {-\frac ba \pm \sqrt{(\frac ba)^2-4\frac ca}}2$
$= \frac {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$.
But you can see why that would cause scratching heads if we taught it that way.
But if $a =1$ (so $p=b;q=c$) it would would work just fine.
====
Full disclosure.  I wouldn't have thought to do it the way the book did.  But I'd do is something fairly equivalent.  I'd have done
$a^2 + 5a + 19 = b^2$
$a^2 + 5a + (19-b^2)=0$
$a =\frac {-5\pm \sqrt{5^2 - 4(19-b^2)}}2=\frac{-5\pm \sqrt{4b^2 -51}}2$.
So then I have to figure which values of integer $b$ give $4b^2 -51$ is a perfect square. Then I'd have pretty much the same insight (but I should have had it sooner) that if
$4b^2 -51 =c^2$ then
$4b^2 -c^2 = (2b-c)(2b+c) = 51$.  As $51$ is either $1\times 51$ or $3\times 17$ we can have $2b-c=1,2b+c=51$ or $2b-c=3;2b+c=17$  That's $b=13$ (and $2b=26$ and  $c=25$) or $b=5$ (and $2b=10$ and  $c=7$).
Hence solutions are $a =\frac {-5\pm \sqrt{4b^2-51}}2=\frac {-5\pm \{25|7\}}2$ and $(a,b) = (-15,13),(10,13),(-6,5),(1,5)$.
(You forgot that $a$ could be negative)

Thank you. I had not seen that manipulation of the quadratic formula before. But when you first saw that equation, did it seem that completing the square was the way to go? Regardless, I wouldn't have the foresight to complete the square because I would've see the all the fractions and thought it a pointless task to find integer solutions that way.

"ut when you first saw that equation, did it seem that completing the square was the way to go?" I imediately thought to use the quadratic formula and difference of two squares is what seemed like the ingenious "Oh, of course" insight. If I were to do this (which I didn't) I'd have done $a=\frac {-5 \pm \sqrt{25 -4(19-b^2)}}2$ and try to solve for $b^2-51$ being a perfect square... which.. I'd do differences of square.  $b^2-51=c^2$ so $b^2-c^2=(a-b)\times (b+c)=51=3\times 17=1\times 15$ yields exactly two solutions. ... So I'd have gotten to difference of squares eventually but not immed.
